# GnatMQ traceability

Tags: c#, mqtt, soa, iot, broker

I am using GnatMQ as a MQTT broker in my IIoT application. I package this as an external class library in my main application which has a Service-Oriented Architecture.

My problem now is that some messages does not reach the broker. I am using M2MQTT to publish messages to the broker. Is there a possibility to log (inside my broker class library) each message that passes the broker? If this is not possible. Can you recommend an alternative C# MQTT broker that I can embedd into my application as a class library or service.